# Return true/false if word in URL matches specific word

Tags: php, joomla

I currently use:

```
    if(strpos($command->href,§current_view) !== false){
        echo '<pre>true</pre>';
    } else {
        echo '<pre>false</pre>';
    }
```

`$command->href` will output something like this: `/path/index.php?option=com_component&view=orders` Whereas
`§current_view` is outputting `orders`. These outputs are dynamically generated, but the scheme will always be the same.

What I need to do is return true/false if the words from `$current_view` match the `view=orders` in the URLs from `$command->href`. The issue with my code is, that it doesnt match anything.
What is the correct way to do this?

Please note that the `$command->href` and the whole code is inside a `while` function, that pass multiple URLs and this only needs to match the same ones.

Comment: `§` shouldn't be `$`?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte yes, sorry for the typo.

Comment: I know you got a answer but actually part of the issue is that you are not using the joomla api for parsing the url.  Hence probably you would have gotten a more complete answer at the joomla stack exchange site [joomla.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking it down to a simple example, using your code and variable values.

```
$current_view = 'orders';
$command = '/path/index.php?option=com_component&view=orders';
if(strpos($command,$current_view) !== false){
    echo '<pre>true</pre>';
}
else {
    echo '<pre>false</pre>';
}
```

The oputput is "true".

Now, go and debug the REAL values of $command->href and $current_view...

I'm pretty confident that the values are not what you *think* they are.

Comment: Wow, it looks like your code works perfectly fine. :) I did the debugging, but I really can't find the reason why the code from Michael W. isn't working. Here is the output with your code: https://imgur.com/a/DwMyuGc

Comment: @YokoGFX It works because he is setting the variable manually. You aren't. There's something wrong with $command->href not returning what you think it should be.

Comment: $command is not an object presumably... I would suggest you add `var_dump($command, $current_view);`  to actually see the real values...

Comment: @MichaelW. No, I use it with $command->href instead of the static $command he used.

Comment: @YoKoGFX Aside from correcting the § to $ error, that's the exact same code you posted in the first place... Did you really have a § in the original code?

Comment: @MichaelW. oh god, i am extremely stupid. You just found the issue. I spent one hour of debugging and it was just this. I am very sorry. When you commented about the § I only saw it in my comments about the code but not in the code itself.

Comment: During development you'll want the error_reporting level HIGH and the screen output ENABLED! Because PHP would have told you what your problem is...

Comment: @LarsStegelitz I have, but it somehow didn't showed it. I really have no Idea how this even happened. Usually it shows things like this, but even PhpStorm didn't showed this error.

Comment: I'm using also PHPStorm and it actually complains about '§current_view' that it is an undefined constant (yellowish background). Basically only a warning. Adding `define('§current_view', 'huhu');` before your code and PHPStorm doesn't complain. Fun fact: '§current_view' is actually an allowed name for a constant :)

Comment: @YoKoGFX Is § a common symbol in your native language? This is a pretty hard symbol to do on accident in English!

Comment: @MichaelW. Well, it is one key to the left on a QWERZ Keyboard.

Comment: @YokoGFX Interesting! TIL!

Answer (score 0):

Does something like:

> if(substr($command->href, strrpos($command->href, '&') + 6) == $current_view)

accomplish what you are after?

To explain, strpos get the *last* instance of a character in a string (& for you, since you said it always follows the scheme). Then we move over 6 characters to take "&view=" out of the string.

You should now be left with "orders" == "orders".

Or do you sometimes include some arguments after the view?

Comment: The issue is that it is not always 6 characters moved, as it is dynamic.

Comment: It's not always going to be "&view="? You can always base it off the final "=" instead of the "&", then.

Comment: Oh, yes it is always &views= but it somehow still doesn't match :/

Comment: You need to do some debugging, then, because I just ran this code and it works perfectly. Can you verify what $command->href is actually returning?

Comment: The $command->href is outputting something like this: /path/index.php?option=com_component&view=categories

Comment: "Something like this?" How about a var_dump? Your values are not what you think they are.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the debugging: https://imgur.com/a/wuMLPbc the first line is from $current_view. The lines below are passed from the while loop and checked against your code.

Comment: Do this: var_dump($command->href). Copy and paste the entire result.

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing url, extracting your `view` query string value and compare it to `$current_view`

```
$query= [];
parse_str(parse_url($command->href)['query'], $query);

if($current_view === $query["view"])
    echo '<pre>true</pre>';
} else {
    echo '<pre>false</pre>';
}
```